# Linux console login with screwed up home permissions

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 server where the /home perms have been mucked up. Now when I try and login I get:

```
Could not chdir to home directory /home/myuser: Permission denied
/bin/bash: Permission denied
Connection to myserver closed.
```

Any suggestions on how I can salvage this server. I have sudoer rights.

Comment: Home permissions alone shouldn't be a problem, however it seems that you can't access bash executable, so no shell gets launched. What you get after this error? I guess you can't login with root user either, as otherwise you wouldn't ask this question. If you have physical access to the server you can boot from a rescue media, mount your partitions and fix permissions. I can't come up with any easier solution, but maybe someone else will.

Comment: I updated the output above. I get disconnected from the server.

Comment: You could try to run a different shell with `ssh server /bin/static-sh` or you could try `sftp server` and then take a look on what the problem with permissions actually is. If the permissions on `/` have been changed to allow access for nobody, I would expect both of those approaches to fail. The best option might very well be to boot the server from a netboot image.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a weird one.

Assuming /bin/bash still exists and is executable by root, you should be able to reboot the machine in single user mode - edit Grub or equivalent by adding init=/bin/bash to the command line which will give you a command prompt without anything extra.   (You might need to mount / -o remount,rw to get your disk writable).   Once you have done this you can chmod the files in your home directory.

Of-course, that you don't have appropriate permissions on /bin/bash is very sinister.   You may need to boot using a rescue disk of some description - Systemrescue or TRK - or even a "live CD" runnable disk can be enough.   You will then need to mount the affected drive offline and change the permissions.   At this point though, you might want to consider if you are better off doing a reinstall as it sounds like your permissions are very hosed - ie its not just /home, its everything.

Answer (score 0):

Well, just recover the root password if you have physical access:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

Comment: this won't work as he hasnt lost his access, he cant log in after the password has been accepted.

Comment: It's not the root account, it's another account. See: Could not chdir to home directory /home/myuser: